# CMake fails in linking

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` for my `C++` project that works perfectly on Windows, using `MSVC`, and on Linux with `gcc`. I am trying to also use the same file for cross-compiling on Windows for Linux.

I am using `Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles` as the generator to create a make file project in Eclipse. In order to use the cross compiler I have created the following toolchain file

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

set(TOOL_CHAIN_ROOT "C:/mgc/embedded/codebench")

# specify the cross compiler
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${TOOL_CHAIN_ROOT}/bin/x86_64-amd-linux-gnu-gcc.exe)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOL_CHAIN_ROOT}/bin/x86_64-amd-linux-gnu-g++.exe)
set(_ECLIPSE_VERSION "4.5")
```

and this is how I am generating the project files

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../Source/cross-tool.cmake ../Source`
```

I don't have any problem here. I can even compile the source files with

```
cmake --build .
```

The project starts to compile but at the very end when it is trying to link it fails with this error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable crossProject
x86_64-amd-linux-gnu-g++.exe: error: CMakeFiles/crossProject.dir/Path/To/ObjectFile.cpp.o: No such file or directory
make.exe[2]: *** [crossProject] Error 1
make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/crossProject.dir/all] Error 2
make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

But when I check `CMakeFiles/crossProject.dir` I can see the object file that it is complaining it can not find. It's right there.

I have been using this cross-compiler for a while and I am sure it is working properly. I am actually building the same project using the same cross-compiler with Eclipse internal builder without CMake. So the problem should not be with the cross-compiler itself.

Is this normal that it is using the `x86_64-amd-linux-gnu-g++.exe` to link instead of `x86_64-amd-linux-gnu-ld.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Windows, not the compiler nor CMake. You can read more about it [here](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/03/29/solving-the-8192-character-command-line-limit-on-windows/) but the gist of it is that there is a 8192 character limit in Windows command line. Basically you can not run any command longer than 8192 characters. The link command that CMake was trying to execute has 11353 characters and that's why it fails with that error.

The solution is to use a different shell. As mentioned in the blog post you can download the GNU ARM Eclipse Build Tools from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuarmeclipse/files/Build%20Tools/).

Once downloaded and installed just copy `make.exe` and `sh.exe` from `<Installation-Path>/bin`to wherever your tool chain is and link like a boss!

I've tried it with different compilers, `qnx - gcc - cross gcc` and it works perfectly.